# Compare Table column with JSON object and update another column in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-table

This is the first time I'm using HTML and Javascript to create a Dashboard. This Dashboard contains a HTML table which contains server name,server desc and time UP,warning critical columns.

From Nagios JSON query generator, I will generate a Availability report URL which returns the JSON value. Now I need to compare the Service Desc in table column and update the the remaining columns by fetching value from the JSON output. How to achieve it.

HTML :

```
<table id="service_table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Service Name</th>
                            <th>Service Desc</th>
                            <th>Time OK %</th>
                            <th>Time Warning %</th>
                            <th>Time Critical %</th>
                        </tr
                    </thead>
                     <tbody>
          <tr>
                    <td>jenkinsserver</td>
                    <td>Jenkins PROD GUI</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>nexusserver</td>
                    <td>nexus GUI</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>sonarserver</td>
                    <td>sonrqube GUI</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="bold" style="text-align:center">CLEARCASE</td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
                    <td>clearcasewebserver</td>
                    <td>clearcase web</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>clearcase server</td>
                    <td>check clearcase status</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Javascript:

```
function make_base_auth(user, password) {
            var tok = user + ':' + password;
            var hash = btoa(tok);
            return 'Basic ' + hash;
} 
$(document).ready(function(){

var end1 =  Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000);
var start1 = Math.floor(time.setDate(time.getDate() - 1)/1000);
console.log(end1);
console.log(start1);

servicereport = " http://xx.xx.xx/nagios/cgi-bin/archivejson.cgi?query=availability&availabilityobjecttype=servicegroups&hostgroup=ALM&servicegroup=ALM+Tools&assumedinitialhoststate=up&assumedinitialservicestate=ok&starttime=" + start1 + "&endtime=" + end1;
$.support.cors = true;

 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: servicereport,
 crossDomain: true,
 async: false,
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',
                        make_base_auth("nagiosadmin", "nagiosadmin"));
                },

 dataType: 'json',     //data format
 success: servicedisplay
 });
function servicedisplay(series) {
  // 1. remove all existing rows

    $('#service_table tbody').empty();

    var lent = series.data.servicegroup.services;
    var aa = lent.length;
    var sm = 0;
    var avg = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<aa; i++) {
        var dataO=series.data.servicegroup.services[i].time_ok;
        var dataW=series.data.servicegroup.services[i].time_warning;
        var dataC=series.data.servicegroup.services[i].time_critical;
        var dataA=(dataO/(dataO + dataW + dataC))*100;
        sm +=dataA;
        }
        avg = sm/aa;
        if ( avg < 100 ) {
        $('#almserv').css('background-color','red');
    } else {
        $('#almserv').css('background-color','green');
        }
    $('#servnum').text(parseFloat(avg).toFixed(2));

    $.each(series.data.servicegroup.services, function (index, serv) {

  $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(parseFloat((serv.time_ok/(serv.time_ok + serv.time_warning + serv.time_critical)*100)).toFixed(2)),
            $('<td>').text(parseFloat((serv.time_warning/(serv.time_ok + serv.time_warning + serv.time_critical)*100)).toFixed(2)),
            $('<td>').text(parseFloat((serv.time_critical/(serv.time_ok + serv.time_warning + serv.time_critical)*100)).toFixed(2)),
        ).appendTo('#service_table');           
    });
```

Comment: It seems like the table is somehow static, just updated with the alerts, so add to the alert field in the table an id that you can use from the ajax call, so every time you fetch your ajax, you update the content of the table directly without going through it.

Comment: First 2 columns of HTML table is static. I need to compare the value in the 2nd column with JSON output and update column 3,4 and 5 in HTML

Comment: That's what I mean, add an id like col3+"2ndColValuel", col4+"2ndColValuel", col5+"2ndColValuel" so when you receive the ajax result you just have to get the field that you were going to compare and use it as "key" like col3+"ajaxField", col4+"ajaxField", col5+"ajaxField", avoiding the comparing part and making it more efficient time-wise.

Comment: Got it. Could you please share a code snippet, It will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea could be something like this:

```
<table id="service_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Service Name</th>
                        <th>Service Desc</th>
                        <th>Time OK %</th>
                        <th>Time Warning %</th>
                        <th>Time Critical %</th>
                    </tr
                </thead>
                 <tbody>
      <tr>
                <td>jenkinsserver</td>
                <td>Jenkins PROD GUI</td>
                <td><div id="Col3JPG">0.00</div></td>
                <td><div id="Col4JPG">0.00</div></td>
                <td><div id="Col5JPG">0.00</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>nexusserver</td>
                <td>nexus GUI</td>
                <td><div id="Col3NG">0.00</div></td>
                <td><div id="Col4NG">0.00</div></td>
                <td><div id="Col5NG">0.00</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>sonarserver</td>
                <td>sonrqube GUI</td>
                <td><div id="Col3JPG">0.00</div></td>
                <td><div id="Col4SG">0.00</div></td>
                <td><div id="Col5SG">0.00</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td colspan="5" class="bold" style="text-align:center">CLEARCASE</td>
                </tr>
      <tr>
                <td>clearcasewebserver</td>
                <td>clearcase web</td>
                <td><div id="Col3CW">0.00</div></td>
                <td><div id="Col4CW">0.00</div></td>
                <td><div id="Col5CW">0.00</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>clearcase server</td>
                <td>check clearcase status</td>
                <td><div id="Col3CCS">0.00</div></td>
                <td><div id="Col4CCW">0.00</div></td>
                <td><div id="Col5CCW">0.00</div></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
```

Then in your script, you could create a [Switch Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) and do the compare there like:

```
for (var i=0; i<aa; i++) {
  switch(series.data.servicegroup.services[i].VariableWithCol2Content){
   case "Jenkins PROD GUI": //code for the changes
     $("#col3JPG").text(series.data.servicegroup.services[i].time_ok);
     $("#col4JPG").text(series.data.servicegroup.services[i].time_warning);
     $("#col5JPG").text(series.data.servicegroup.services[i].time_critical);
     //add all require code to update the row
   break;
   case "nexus GUI": //code for the changes
     $("#col3NG").text(series.data.servicegroup.services[i].time_ok);
     $("#col4NG").text(series.data.servicegroup.services[i].time_warning);
     $("#col5NG").text(series.data.servicegroup.services[i].time_critical);
     //add all require code to update the row
   break;
     //and so on with all of them...
```